# Location of .testcaferc.json file for Windows

Tags: file, automated-tests, config, e2e-testing, testcafe

Correct location for .testcaferc.json in Windows. Have tried different locations with no success.

TestCafe version: version: 1.3.3.

Have placed file in test file location. The same location of my test.js file.
`C:\Users\zzzzzzz\TestCafeStudio\P@L_Tests`

Have also placed file:
`C:\Users\zzzzzzz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\testcafe`

Contents: .testcaferc.json

```
{
    "quarantineMode": false,
    "debugMode": true,
    "debugOnFail": true,
    "stopOnFirstFail": true,
    "skipJsErrors": true,
    "skipUncaughtErrors": true,
    "appInitDelay": 3000,
    "concurrency": 3,
    "selectorTimeout": 3000,
    "assertionTimeout": 1000,
    "pageLoadTimeout": 1000,
    "speed": 0.1,
    "proxy": "www-vvvvv.bbbbb.com:80"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

TestCafe can detect your configuration file only if it is located in the current working directory. You can use the `cwd` command to view your current working directory and the `cd` command to change it.